# GFCI master works but others in chain aren’t

Tags: electrical, gfci

The GFC outlet in the garage is linked to 5 outlets in the kitchen, as well as to the garage door. The outlet in the garage and the garage door works and it resets, etc as it should. The outlets it controls in the kitchen however, are dead. The breaker is fine for the master GCFI circuit. I am at a loss to why this GFCI receptacle isn’t powering the rest of the receptacles on the circuit.

Comment: maybe it has nothing to do with being a GFCI and is just a plain vanilla wiring problem. Problems in wires are rare unless you've recently done construction, so check wire ends at the last good and first bad place. Backstabs are particularly notable failure points.

Comment: If you redo any of this wiring, you may not be able to share the circuit between the garage and the kitchen. Check your local codes to see your jurisdiction says about kitchen circuits outside the kitchen.

Comment: I'm guessing the GFCI breaker is pretty old (old enough that when new GFCI's still cost enough to justify running the kitchen and the garage off of the same one). It may have just failed. You could check continuity between the garage and the kitchen wires, but I'd first go out and buy a new GFCI outlet for $20 and replace the one in the garage. It would make sense for it to fail with an open circuit.

Comment: Regarding possible code issues of sharing the circuit between the garage and kitchen. This is probably fine since it is existing work. In my city at least, things like this are grandfathered in. Repairs to old work don't need to meet current codes. The only thing they don't grandfather in my city is smoke alarms--I had to install one in every bedroom instead of just having one in the hallway.

Comment: @HariGanti you're always allowed to do *repairs to broken stuff*.  That's how Home Depot excuses selling NEMA 10 receptacles.

Comment: @Harper In my jurisdiction, if you are going to modify something, including for the purpose of repair, it needs to be done to current code. I actually just discussed this with a code consultant at my city's permit office. Definitely depends on your jurisdiction.

Comment: Thank you all. The house is under 5 years old and there hasn’t been any construction that would affect the wiring. I will pull out & check the outlets in the chain to see if there is anything obvious that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I can't buy that the GFCI in the garage is powering circuits in your kitchen. Kitchen receptacles are usually powered by small appliance circuits which are 20A and there must be at least 2 of these in the Kitchen/Nook/Dining area. NEC Article 220.52 (A). This is actually in my 1965 code book so it has been around for almost every dwelling in the US. These circuits by code are separate from any other circuits.

I would look for a different circuit breaker or a GFCI powering the receptacles in the kitchen. If it isn't a breaker look for GFCI receptacles that are hidden. Like behind the refrigerator.

Good luck.

Comment: "almost every dwelling in the US" - not quite. My hours is from the mid 50s and, until I redid my kitchen ~ 18 years ago, there were not enough outlets in the kitchen and the few that were there were shared circuits with outlets all over the house.